# CMake: How an item in find_package may break a program?

Tags: c++, cmake, mutex, catkin

My c++ program was having runtime errors (crash on mutex lock). Exceptions that were not coming directly from my code but from some libraries it used. I started to track down the problem and found out that I had a library (giskard_core, but that doesn't matter) listed in `CMakeLists.txt` in `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ... giskard_core)` which I was not using at the moment. Commenting it out fixed the crash I was investigating. Pulling it back to the `find_package` list brought the crash back.
My code was really simple, literally just a main function and bare bones of a ROS application, and surely was not using the library that was causing the problems.

What is going on? Can a package bring an error by just being listed in `find_package` in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your code probably has an error in how it implements catkin stuff.  Since it's actually compiling without that project, I also suspect that it has some pre-processor guards which are only enabled when catkin has been found.

Does something like this exist in your CMakeLists.txt?

```
if (Catkin_FOUND)
  add_definitions(-DCATKIN_FOUND)
endif (Catkin_FOUND)
```

Also does something like this exist in your code?

```
#ifdef CATKIN_FOUND
  mutex.lock()
#endif
```

If so, that could explain the issues that you're seeing.  You'd need to fix the use of whatever Catkin functionality your project implements.

Comment: Well, my code does not implement anything yet. It's the simplest ROS program with just `main` function. But just pulling in the guilty library into find_package makes it crash. `CMakeLists.txt` has no conditionals nor has the C++ code. You mentioned pre-processor guards... but should the compiler ever see the code from the library when it's not even used?

Comment: In this case, I suspect that `catkin` initializes some global object and that initialization causes the crash, likely due to some missing initial configuration.  Check out [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and check that your CMakeLists.txt configures catkin according to those instructions.